# "Contronominale" proposition

Tags: logic

Given an implication to prove, say p implies q, it is well known that it is equivalent to prove -q implies -p. In italian this second equivalent proposition is called "contronominale" of the previous proposition. How is it called in english?

Comment: And, even if you are not asking for it, _Contraposición_ in Spanish, _Kontraposition_ in German and _Contraposée_ in French.

Comment: "Contrapositive" in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The English term is [Contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).

Comment: I did not find any Italian page on wikipedia dedicated to _contronominale_. I can't speak Italian (well, I've never tried), so maybe there is one, but I just missed it. If you want to have a look and find one, I will link the English page with the Italian one (on wikipedia of course).

Comment: @anderstood - see [Implicazione logica](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicazione_logica).

Comment: That's the one I found but it does not correspond exactly to contrapositive (it's more general). Nevermind and thank you for searching.

Comment: @anderstood - but the Italian Wiki page mix "logical implication" with "conditional", and this - IMO - is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

In English we call this the "contrapositive".